# How to Render a String by Laravel Template Engine

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How can I render an string which contains blade syntax?

```
View::render('{{$var}}')->with('var', $var); // Like this for Example
```

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: I need a RESTful API that can render posted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for

https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler

This package allows you to compile blade strings.

Comment: AFAIK no, thats why this package exists.

Comment: I always get "realpath() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given" error though with render() method